# Using Excel Linest function with blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need `LINEST` function to be applied with blank cells to get the slope parameter as well as the associated standard error. I can get the slope parameter with a normal function that may resolve the problem via other complementary functions, but not its standard error, I think. Is there any solution for using `LINEST` with blank cells in array form? Any ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are looking for - what do you mean by "associated standard error"? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

I’m guessing you have something like

[image: Excel worksheet with missing data]

where B = 2×A+3, but with some B data missing.  Filter out your blank Y (B) values:

[image: filter dialog box][image: ->][image: resulting filtered data view]

Now select your data, type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, copy, and paste somewhere (probably a new sheet would be good).  You now have just your complete data:

[image: data with no rows with missing data]

and you should be able to get your stats from that.

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I needed it to do. What exactly does the `Alt`+`;` shortcut do? I know it works, but I can't figure out what exactly it's doing.

Comment: @stephenwade: Its name is “Select Visible Cells” or “Select Visible Cells Only”.  I guess the simplest explanation is that, if you have a bunch of cells selected, and some of them are hidden (by explicitly Hiding rows or columns, or through Filtering), this command de-selects the hidden ones.  You can also perform this function by Home (tab) –> Editing (panel) –> Find & Select –> Go To Special –> Visible Cells Only.  You can add it to your Quick Access Toolbar if you want (look for “Select Visible Cells” in the “Commands Not in the Ribbon” group).