# How can I remove 'blank' or ' ' data in my excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with some cells have 'digits' data, and other have blank or ' ' data.

How can I remove all the cell with blank or ' ' data so that when I plot a graph, it does not treat it as '0'?

Thank you.

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/480068/150988) to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/480034/using-excel-linest-function-with-blank-cells).

Answer (score 2):

Fill the blanks with #N/A.
You can do a select special blanks (<kbd>F5</kbd>), type #N/A and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fill your cells. 
This should take them out of your graph.

Comment: True blank cells in Excel are not plotted by default. "" in a cell is text, not blank, and is treated as a zero. #N/A is not plotted in line or scatter plots.