# Copy only remaining rows after filter to new Excel Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel 2010 conditional formatting: selectively highlighting duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/459541/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-selectively-highlighting-duplicates)

I have an Excel file with an external data connection set up. It pulls data in directly from a database, and gives us about 450 rows. The header row allows us to filter the data in the sheet, and we use this as a general purpose tool... I will use the filters to narrow down what I'm looking at based on criteria that change depending on the circumstance.

Often, after filtering the data, I want to send just the filtered records to another person. I'd like to copy/paste just the remaining rows into a new Workbook to send via e-mail. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I paste the data, it still pastes *all* the data. The filtered rows are still in the workbook... they're just hidden. I want them gone from the new file completely.

How can I do this?

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/480068/150988) to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/480034/using-excel-linest-function-with-blank-cells).

Comment: @Scott Hey, that worked... well enough (had to redo the styling and filters, but that's easy enough). If you post an answer here with the correct name for the `alt+;` feature, I will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After filtering the data (i.e., hiding the data you want to exclude),

1. Select the visible data that you want to export.
2. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>.  This is a shortcut for the Select Visible Cells command, which you can add to your Quick Access Toolbar if you want (look in the “Commands Not in the Ribbon” group).
3. Copy, and paste into a new workbook.  You’ll get *just* the visible data.

Comment: Actually this does not work (the alt + ;). I am on Mac OS. In order to get ; you also have to press Shift. that's ok?

Comment: Sure, whatever deselects the data that aren’t visible.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but `alt/option + ;` works in Mac