# Copy/Paste including Hidden Columns when Filtering Rows in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I suspect the solution will be related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/480034/using-excel-linest-function-with-blank-cells)??

I have a spreadsheet that comes to me pre-formatted with hidden columns sprinkled in multiple places (for viewing brevity's sake). I need to turn on filtering, apply a filter to one of the columns, and then paste the resulting rows to a new sheet  - **including** the hidden columns (lather, rinse, repeat). I'd prefer to not undo/re-do the hidden columns unless I have to. Is it possible to paste the hidden columns without adding the extra steps?

Comment: Related to it, but sort of the opposite problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the automated undo feature of Excel (ctrl-z)?  I.e. ...

- select the whole spreadsheet
- unhide
- do your filtering
- select and copy what you want
- ctrl-z  ( to undo things)
- paste

Comment: If I only had to do it once or twice, sure. But I need to do many and often.

Comment: I see on the Advanced Filter window, there is an option "Copy to another location." Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this often, you would better write a macro for the entire operation. Excel has a built-in macro recorder which can be helpful to save the steps as Visual Basic source code in your personal macro workbook.

I don't know whether you're familiar with programming - if you can do some basic coding, extending Excel with a personal toolkit for common operations can save a lot of time. If you want to get deeper, it's possible to create a fully fledged Excel add-in using Visual Basic for Applications (for example), which could add a button to the Ribbon which could start this custom functionality and so on.